# OpenCV/PythonGUI, displaying openCV image into tkinter?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to do the following, but I can not find the right code.

GUI1:

1. 2 buttons, button 1 = load terrain, button 2 = find craters
2. if you press button 1 it will open file explorer and you can choose an image
3. the image you choose will show up into the GUI

OpenCV:

1. it will read the image you chose
2. it will find all the circles in that image
3. it will show into the python console

GUI2:

4. if you press button 2 it will open the (OpenCV) image into the GUI

Right now I can't figure out how to open the (OpenCV) image into the GUI.
It only opens into the python Console.

My code is down below

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title("Armstrong Autonomous Moon Landing System")
root.geometry("1100x600")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/brett/')


mb = Menubutton(root, text="Armstrong Autonomouse Moon Lander System")
mb.menu = Menu(mb)
mb["menu"] = mb.menu


##########  ALL OTHER CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE

def openfile():
    return filedialog.askopenfilename()


def open():
    global my_image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/test3/images", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"),("all files", "*.*")))
    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    my_image_label = Label(image=my_image).pack()
    
def find_craters():
    circles_image = cv2.imread(root.filename)
    if circles_image.shape[-1] == 3: # color image
        b,g,r = cv2.split(circles_image) # get b,g,r
        rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b]) # switch it to rgb
        gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(circles_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray_img = circles_image

    img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 5)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
    param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0,:]:

    # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cimg)
    plt.show()
    
 ###   HOW RETURN CIRCLES_IMAGE TO TKINTER
    # circles_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()
    # circles_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(cimg))
    # circles_image_label = Label(image=circles_image).pack()
    #circles_img = Label(root, image= cimg).pack()
 
    
    
    # plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cimg)
    # plt.show()
  
my_btn = Button(root, text="Load Terrain", command=open).pack()  
my_btn2 = Button(root, text="Find Craters", command=find_craters).pack()
#my_btn3 = Button(root, text="  About Me  ").pack()

mb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I would like some help

Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you Pillow with ImageTk and set it to label in Tkinter.

```
import cv2
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

'''convert cv2 image to image tkinter to set image to label'''
def cv2_to_imageTK(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    imagePIL = PIL.Image.fromarray(image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = imagePIL)
    return imgtk

imgtk = cv2_to_imageTK(img)
label.imgtk = imgtk
label.configure(image = imgtk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `PIL.Image` to `OpenCV` image, find the circles using the `OpenCV` image. Then draw those found circles onto the `OpenCV` image and convert back to `PIL.Image`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import cv2


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Armstrong Autonomous Moon Landing System")
root.geometry("1100x600")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/brett/')


##########  ALL OTHER CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE


def open():
    global my_image
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="images", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"),("all files", "*.*")))
    my_label.config(text=filename)
    my_image = Image.open(filename)
    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)
    my_image_label.config(image=tkimg)
    my_image_label.image = tkimg  # save a reference of the image


def find_craters():
    # convert PIL image to OpenCV image
    circles_image = np.array(my_image.convert('RGB'))
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(circles_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 5)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
                               param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

        for i in circles[0]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(circles_image, (i[0],i[1]), i[2], (0,255,0), 2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(circles_image, (i[0],i[1]), 2, (0,0,255), 3)

        # convert OpenCV image back to PIL image
        image = Image.fromarray(circles_image)
        # update shown image
        my_image_label.image.paste(image)


tk.Button(root, text="Load Terrain", command=open).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Find Craters", command=find_craters).pack()

# for the filename of selected image
my_label = tk.Label(root)
my_label.pack()

# for showing the selected image
my_image_label = tk.Label(root)
my_image_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TheUlitmateJackson Notice that you have used my code in your new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887472/opencv-gui-i-need-to-add-a-blur-to-my-image).  If it solves this question, consider accept it as the answer.